# Screen rotation on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Lenovo Ideapad Miix 510

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, tablet, display-rotation, orientation

I recently upgraded my Lenovo Ideapad Miix 510 from 16.04 to 18.04 and was pleasantly surprised to find that my previously nonfunctional screen autorotation started working with the upgrade. Unfortunately, the autorotation is always 90 degrees counterclockwise relative to the actual orientation of the tablet unless I lock the rotation. Also if I reorient the tablet too frequently without locking the screen rotation, the screen goes solid grey and the whole system hangs.

Settings -> Displays does not have an Orientation or Rotation section, presumably because of autorotation. Using xrandr with -o or --rotate yields

> Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyCan't open display :0

Is there a way to leave autorotation enabled, but tell Ubuntu to always present the screen 90 degrees clockwise from what it thinks the orientation should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just run a MIIX 510 myself. They’re a great little Surface Pro like device that works fairly well under Ubuntu 18.04.

I’ve managed to sort out Screen Rotation under Ubuntu. Out of the box my display is rotated 90 degrees clockwise, but it can be fixed by mapping the sensor data. Apparently the Hardware Accelerometer data needs to be translated for the screen rotation to work well.

Details for a complete and more accurate match for the MIIX 510 Hardware Accelerometer mapping that is needed can be found here:
https://npm.pkg.github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/hwdb/60-sensor.hwdb

The following steps will map the data correctly for MIIX 510 screen rotation under Ubuntu 18.04:

1) Install iio-sensor-proxy if you've removed it

2) Fix the issue by hacking a sensor match and and mapping by creating the file with the following file /etc/udev/hwdb.d/60-sensor.hwdb with this content:

```
sensor:modalias:*
  ACCEL_MOUNT_MATRIX=0, -1, 0; -1, 0, 0; 0, 0, 1
```

3) Run the command:

sudo systemd-hwdb update

4) Reboot

Comment: That worked, thank you! Did you ever get the webcams to work?

Answer (score 1):

Occasionally see this question.

A fix from me has been merged into systemd and this issue should be fix on systemd>=240

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/11108

Comment: Thanks so much for responding, I'd given up hope! Is there anything particular I need to do to make this work, or just wait for the next update push?

Comment: If your systemd version is greater than 240, so Miix510 should works out of box.  Else you need to see https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/hwdb/60-sensor.hwdb this file, and import miix510 configs to your device configuation.

Comment: By the way, miix510 serie has multiple product. `sensor:modalias:acpi:*BOSC0200*:dmi:*:svnLENOVO*:pn80U1:*` will match miix510-12ISK .  If you are not this product, the string will be different.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand upon the accepted answer with my experience for the non coder/mathematician's out there like myself...

### How I got there

(Around the houses and up the garden path)

I took many wrong turns, wondering why nothing was happening when I tried altering values in the sensor matrix. Error number one was researching rotation matrices (this is about direction not rotation) and number two was not watching the indentation and spaces, **this is *extremely* important**.

#### Setup

The orientation data is generated by an accelerometer, i.e. a sensor which reports which way is up. The i2c sensor bus can accept 3 axis gyroscope, accelerometer and compass, though we are only interested in the accelerometer. This is handled by the iio-sensor-proxy.service and configured in `/usr/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60.sensor.hwdb`. Check this file to see if the device is listed. If not, this file contains helpful information on how to go about customising with a configuration file at `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/61-sensor.hwdb`. This file will append the system file (it is read after it at the initialisation of the hardware database) and will persist after any system updates.

#### Identifying the tablet and sensor

On the back of the case of my tablet it states "*Toshiba WT10a 102*". To find the full DMI string  or modalias of the device use `cat /sys/class/dmi/id/modalias`. This returns:

```
dmi:bvnToshiba:bvr2.00:bd01/09/2015:br2.0:efr19.0:svnTOSHIBA:pnTOSHIBAWT10-A-102:pvrPDWOBE-00800TEN:rvnType2-BoardManufacturer:rnType2-BoardProductNAme:rvrType2-BoardVersion:cvnChasisManufacturer:ct10:cvrChassisVersion:
```

To find the details for the sensor use `udevadm info -q path -n /dev/iio:device*`. This returns:

```
/devices/platform/80860F41:02/i2c-2/i2c-INVN6500:00/iio:device0
```

This can be used to find the device modalias in the sensor parent with `` cat /sys/`udevadm info -q path -n /dev/iio:device0`/../modalias ``. This returns:

```
acpi:INVN6500:
```

The device label (if it exists) can be found in the label file of the sensor with `` cat /sys/`udevadm info -q path -n /dev/iio:device0`/label ``. In my case this returns:

```
cat: 'sys/devices/platform/80860F41:02/i2c-2/i2c-INVN6500:00/iio:device0/label': No such file or directory
```

#### The hwdb.d file

It's useful to see if there is an existing similar configuration in the hwdb.d file so `cat /usr/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-sensor.hwdb | grep -i -A1 'toshiba'`. This returns:

```
# Toshiba
#########################################
--
# Toshiba Encore WT10A tablet
sensor:modalalias:acpi:INV6500*:dmi:*:svnTOSHIBA:pnTOSHIBAWT10-A-103:*
 ACCEL_MOUNT_MATRIX=0, -1, 0; -1, 0, 0; 0, 0, 1
```

Where the format is:

```
sensor:modalias:<parent modalias pattern>:dmi:<dmi pattern>
or 
sensor:<label>:modalias:<parent modalias pattern>:dmi:<dmi pattern>
```

Here the match is made against `acpi:INV6500*`(sensor parent modalias plus wildcard) and `:svnTOSHIBA:pnTOSHIBAWT10-A-103:`(dmi system vendor and product name surrounded by wildcards). The colons surrounding the vendor and product name appear superfluous. The matrix describes swapping and inverting the x and y directions.

OK, so I was lucky and had a close match. A simple edit to the product name and update could possibly get me on my way. It would have done, however a typo (yes, one of those spaces) meant I could not solve this and so I went further into trying to figure out the matrices.

#### Matrices

The orientation matrix is used to allow for the possible variations in mounting the accelerometer in the device. Possible values in the 3 x 3 matrix are 1, 0, and -1. For each axis of the accelerometer, a line in the matrix defines the mapping to an axis of the output. The first line of the matrix (first 3 numbers of the hwdb.d file) define whether data from the accelerometers x axis is assigned to the x, y, or z axis of output via 1 (select), 0 (ignore) or -1 (negated). Each line should have one and only one output.

This is how I came to understand the matrix after some false starts. It made sense to me as a series of switches mapping an input to an output as follows.

| inputs from accelerometer | x | y | z | outputs from matrix |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| input(*x*) | *x out* | *y out* | *z out* | output(*x*) |
| input(*y*) | *x out* | *y out* | *z out* | output(*y*) |
| input(*z*) | *x out* | *y out* | *z out* | output(*z*) |

where

|  | x | y | z |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *x in* | 1 | 0 | 0 | *x* out |
| *y in* | 0 | 1 | 0 | *y* out |
| *z in* | 0 | 0 | 1 | *z* out |

is the identity matrix i.e. no change. If *x* input is 1 *x* out equals 1 and so on.
In the hwdb.d file this would be written as `1,0,0;0,1,0;0,0,1`

|  | x | y | z |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *x in* | 0 | 0 | 1 | *z* out |
| *y in* | 0 | -1 | 0 | *-y* out |
| *z in* | 1 | 0 | 0 | *x* out |

swaps *x* and *z* and negates the *y* value.
In the hwdb.d file this would be written as `0,0,1;0,-1,0;1,0,0`

I think a more mathematically correct understanding is that the matrix is a form of [logical matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_matrix) known as a [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) in the field of [vector space orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(vector_space)). Here the number of columns in the first matrix must equal the number of rows in the second and the result of the multiplication has the same number of rows as the first matrix and the same number of columns as the second.

|  | *x* is up | *y* is up | *z* is up | multiplied by |  |  |  | results in |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *x* | ***1*** | **0** | **0** |  | ***0*** | 0 | 1 |  | ***0*** | 0 | 1 |
| *y* | 0 | 1 | 0 |  | **0** | -1 | 0 |  | 0 | -1 | 0 |
| *z* | 0 | 0 | 1 |  | **1** | 0 | 0 |  | 1 | 0 | 0 |

The multiplication works by multiplying the numbers of the first row with the first column in the second matrix and adding them up, then the first row with the second column etc. As the first matrix is the identity with no -1 values and only -1, 0, 1 values exist in the matrices, with only one entry per row or column, it's really just a case of finding the 1 in the row of the first matrix and selecting the number in the corresponding column of the second and then filling in the zeroes. The result is always the same as the orientation matrix.

### Testing the tablet

A bit of searching on the internet and I worked out the chip was an MPU-6050 from InvenSense.TDK and even found the specs showing the axis.
[image: sensor axis][image: screen axis]

Time to test using the diagnostics from https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/hadess/iio-sensor-proxy. `monitor-sensor` reports back some details of the sensor and then continues to report back it's output as you move the tablet device.

| tablet | expected | sensor reported | actual | display |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| top up | y=1 | left up | x=-1 | [image: screen top up] |
| left up | x=-1 | normal | y=1 | [image: screen left up] |
| bottom up | y=-1 | right up | x=1 | [image: screen bottom up] |
| right up | x=1 | bottom up | y=-1 | [image: screen right up] |

[image: incorrect orientation]

From this it can be seen that x and y need to be swapped and negated ie *x = -y* and *y=-x* and *z* has no bearing so can stay the same. This can be written as:

|  | x | y | z |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *x* in | 0 | -1 | 0 | *-y* out |
| *y* in | -1 | 0 | 0 | *-x* out |
| *z* in | 0 | 0 | 1 | *z* out |

swaps and negates *x* and *y* leaves *z* unchanged.
In the hwdb.d file this would be written as `0,-1,0;-1,0,0;0,0,1`

.....Which is exactly the same as the existing Toshiba entry in the hwdb.d. Doh!

[image: corrected orientation]

### Creating the hwdb.d entry

It is recommended to add an entry in a file `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/61-sensor.hwdb` to append your rule to those already in `/user/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-sensor.hwdb`. Be careful if copy - pasting to ensure there are spaces in all the right places and no more! `sudo nano /etc/udev/hwdb.d/60-sensor.hwdb` or `sudo gedit /etc/udev/hwdb.d/60-sensor.hwdb` and add the necessary lines such as:

```
#########################################
# Toshiba
#########################################

# Toshiba Encore WT10-A-102 tablet
sensor:modalalias:acpi:INV6500*:dmi:*svnTOSHIBA:pnTOSHIBAWT10-A-102*
 ACCEL_MOUNT_MATRIX=0, -1, 0; -1, 0, 0; 0, 0, 1
```

It is suggested to contribute to the systemd project on github by supplying your configuration. In that case a more general rule might apply to catch both the 102 and 103 tablets in the `/user/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-sensor.hwdb` file as follows:

```
#########################################
# Toshiba
#########################################

# Toshiba Encore WT10-A type 102 and 103 tablets
sensor:modalalias:acpi:INV6500*:dmi:*svnTOSHIBA:pnTOSHIBAWT10-A-10*
 ACCEL_MOUNT_MATRIX=0, -1, 0; -1, 0, 0; 0, 0, 1
```

### Restart with new settings

For the changes to take effect the hardware database has to be updated and the sensor service restarted. This can be done with:

```
sudo systemd-hwdb update
sudo udevadm trigger -v -p DEVNAME=/dev/iio:device0
sudo systemctl restart iio-sensor-proxy.service
```

### Commands

`cat /sys/class/dmi/id/modalias` or
`cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/modalias` to see full dmi of tablet where

> bvn =   (BIOS vendor)
> bvr =   (BIOS version)
> bd  =   (BIOS date)
> br  =   (BIOS release)
> efr =   (EC firmware release)
> svn =   (system vendor)
> pn  =   (product name)
> pvr =   (product version)
> rvn =   (board vendor)
> rn  =   (board name)
> rvr =   (board version)
> cvn =   (chassis vendor)
> ct  =   (chassis type)
> cvr =   (chassis version)
> sku =   (product SKU)

`cat /usr/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-sensor.hwdb` to see the whole configuration file
`cat /usr/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-sensor.hwdb | grep -ignore-case --after-context=1 'toshiba'` to filter down to the tablet manufacturer plus one line of trailing context
`udevadm info --query all --name /dev/iio:device*` finds the sensor in this case kernel device node name 'device0' on 'INVN6500'
`udevadm info --export-db` to verify the sensor is detected, returns the platform, name and more for all udev devices
`udevadm info --export-db | grep iio` to filter down to the sensor
`` cat /sys/`udevadm info --query path --name /dev/iio:device*`/../modalias `` return the sensor parent modalias
`` cat /sys/`udevadm info --query path --name /dev/iio:device*`/label `` return the sensor label (if exists)
`gdbus introspect --system --dest net.hadess.SensorProxy --object-path /net/hadess/SensorProxy` check whether a sensor is detected
`monitor-sensor` to check the sensors output
`sudo dmesg | grep --ignore-case toshiba`  diagnostic messages for the tablet manufacturer (reports "dmi: TOSHIBA TOSHIBA WT10-A-102/Type2")
`sudo dmesg | grep --ignore-case invn6500` diagnostic messages for the sensor (reports the sensor was using identity matrix ie. no change)
`sudo systemd-hwdb update`  update the system with any changes made to configuration
`sudo udevadm trigger --verbose --property-match DEVNAME=/dev/iio:device0`  update the system with any changes made to configuration
`sudo systemctl restart iio-sensor-proxy.service` restart the service to see the effects of any changes made to configuration

### Useful websites

1. https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/hadess/iio-sensor-proxy
2. https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/firmware/dmi-id.c
3. https://github.com/systemd/systemd
4. https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/hwdb.html
5. https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=dfc57732ad38f93ae6232a3b4e64fd077383a0f1
6. https://people.skolelinux.org/pere/blog/Modalias_strings___a_practical_way_to_map__stuff__to_hardware.html
7. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(vector_space)
8. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_matrix
9. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix